# Close Swing Panel within JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx

I have added a JFXPanel that I load via FXMLLoader into a Swing JFrame, all of this works fine so far. The problem is that I would like to terminate the Swing JFrame from within the JavaFXControl-class

```
@FXML
protected void setCancelButton() {
    abstractOptionsFx.dispose();
}
```

I tried dispose as well as WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING, but none of theme seems to be working. Does somebody knows a workaround or is it just impossible?

Comment: `System.exit(0); // will terminate any Java based app. - but look for a cleaner solution`

Comment: I finally found a clean solution: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                abstractOptionsFx.dispose();
            }
        });` More information about JavaFX and Swing integration can be found in this article http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20111112?pg=38#pg37

Comment: Think to close your thread if you found the solution. ;)